# How to use "db:transfer" as a heroku command by heroku-valkyrie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I tried to use heroku-valkyrie to transfer my local data to heroku databse.
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-valkyrie

I installed the plugin:

```
heroku plugins:install http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-valkyrie.git
Installing heroku-valkyrie... done
```

and wanted to transfer data:

```
heroku db:transfer sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://my-apps-database-url/
```

but received this error message:

```
 !    `db:transfer` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

How can I use db:transfer as a heroku command?

Answer (score 0):

According to Heroku documentation, you will have to export your local database as a dump file by using the [pg dump tool](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/backup-dump.html) and import the file using command.,

> heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump'

Check for complete documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: Thanks your reply, but as I wrote I'm using sqlite as local database. I can't use pg dump tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer` first.

Then the command will be `pg:transfer`, not `db:transfer`.

However, you may run into issues since you're transferring from an sqlite database and this command only transfers from postgre.